# What are the best book to learn commutator algebra in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, resource-recommendations, commutator

I am looking for a pretty handy and well described quantum mechanics book where I can find the concept behind commutators in general.

Comment: I think any book on QM would do.

Comment: There's not that much to it, you just need to practice!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by commutator algebra in quantum mechanics? Do you mean by the commutator algebra of symmetry in quantum mechanics? The symmetry in quantum mechanics fulfills a unitary projective representation of the classical symmetry. If you mean representation theory in quantum mechanics, then I recommend the following books.

1. [Foundations of Quantum Theory——From Classical Concepts to Operator Algebras](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-51777-3) (chapter 5)
2. [The Theory of Symmetry Actions in Quantum Mechanics——with an Application to the Galilei Group](https://doi.org/10.1007/b99455) (chapter 3, 4, 5, 6)
3. [From Classical Mechanics to Quantum Field Theory, A Tutorial](https://doi.org/10.1142/11556) (chapter 2)

The above books explain Wigner's theorem and the representation theory of Galilean algebra in great details. Wigner's theorem plays a key role in quantum physics.